# Определить день недели по дате

Tags: php, дата

На странице анкеты имеется пункт дата рождения. При отправке анкеты необходимо чтобы рядом с датой рождения прописывался день недели. Нашла вот такое решение в интернете, но это лишь с текущей датой прокатывает.Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе на начальной странице в календаре выводилась именно выбранная дата, а не текущая?

```
<?php
    // Установливаем русскую локаль
    // или setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU'); в PHP 4
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'rus_RUS');
    // Получаем сегодняшнюю дату
    // Формируем вывод
    // %a - короткая запись дня недели (Чт)
    // %A - обычная запись дня недели (Четверг)
    // %Y - год полностью (2008)
    // %y - год кратко (08)
    // Короче, смотрите маны
    $data = strftime("%a, %d/%m/%Y", time());
    // В PHP4 потребуется конвертация
    // $data = iconv('ISO-8859-5','windows-1251', $data);
    echo $data; // В PHP 4 название дня недели
    // будет начинаться с заглавной буквы
    // в обычной форме записи
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

День недели даты можно узнать следующим образом

```
$date = '2013-01-01';
echo strftime("%a, %d/%m/%Y", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант

```
echo date("D",time());
```