# Как можно ограничить диапазон выбираемой даты?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

```
<form action="" method="">
    <fielset>
      <legend>Local Pickup Date and Time</legend>
      <label>Choose Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="date"></label>
      <label>Choose Time: <input type="time" name="time" id="time"></label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </fielset>
  </form>
```

Как можно ограничить диапазон выбираемой даты и время? Или запретить выбирать дни Воскресенья, например, как это можно сделать с помощью JS на клиенте и PHP на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS не нужен - [читаем](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html), вникаем, понимаем что есть атрибут `min` и `max`.
Example: `<input type="date" min="2015-01-01" max="2016-01-01" />`.
Value: `2015-03-01`.

На PHP можно заюзать `DateTime`: https://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Ограничить дни типа "Воскресенья" - там надо считать.
Например:

```
$dayOfWeek = ["вс", "пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб"];
$str = $dayOfWeek [date("w", mktime (0, 0, 0, $cur_month, $cur_day, $cur_year))];
```

Или так: [Определить день недели по дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226281)

Comment: это же новый формат :)